# Cannot get drop down menu's submenus have same width as their parent

Tags: html, css

I'm a HTML/CSS newbie, and I can't seem to get my submenus have the same width as their parent menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/whitelatino/g8Lxxksg/1/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Musiker del</a> 

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> Musikere </a> 
            </li>
            <!--Make litte hover color change for all nav -->
            <li><a href="#"> Koncerter</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="#">Hyr Kunstnere</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add static width to this

```
nav ul ul li a {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. The next is to make the children look exact like their parents. By that i mean the text in the navigation bar is the same as parent.